# Ruby/Evernote - Correct md5 hash to get resource by hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, evernote

When calling NoteStore.getResourceByHash on the Evernote api, did anyone manage to generate the correct md5 checksum from the hash value of the en-media element, using Ruby?

I've managed to get this working in c# but I cannot seem to get it working with Ruby.

Its about this line:

```
hash_func = Digest::MD5.new
@note_store.getResourceByHash(auth_token, note_guid, hash_func.hexdigest(hash), true, false, false)
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: Done :-). Please un-downvote.

Comment: I would, but it's not my downvote!

Comment: Ha, ok! Thanks though. Any ideas on my question? :-)

Comment: What is `hash` in the above code? The [docs](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceByHash) say "`@param contentHash` The MD5 checksum of the resource within that note. Note that this is the binary checksum, for example from Resource.data.bodyHash, and not the hex-encoded checksum that is used within an en-media tag in a note body," which suggests to me that `hexdigest` is not what you want. Perhaps [`digest`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Instance.html#method-i-digest) would work?

Comment: Resource.data.bodyHash and Digest::MD5.digest yield two different values so I guess Digest::MD5.digest is not the correct way to go... I am finding little resources on this. Any other ideas? :-) This cannot be this hard. I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

This posted helped me solve it: [Creating a byte array in ruby (c# example code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801608/creating-a-byte-array-in-ruby-c-example-code)

```
'string'.scan(/../).map(&:hex).pack('C*')
```

Comment: can you loease tell how to do this python