# Creating a byte array in ruby (c# example code)

Tags: ruby

I need to do something like this, in ruby:

```
    private byte[] ResourceHashToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hash.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2) bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hash.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
```

What would be the optimum/most common/best practice way of doing this in Ruby?

I have tried the following methods to no avail:

```
Digest::MD5.digest(hex)
String.unpack(hex)
String.bytes
```

Comment: If you don't know the answer, just move on. Don't down vote for no reason ;-).

Comment: Just because someone didn't comment, that doesn't mean they don't have a reason for down-voting your question. I will point out that, assuming Ruby has a byte array type at all, creating one in that language should be very straightforward. That you have _no_ Ruby code at all in your question (which is really not a C# question at all and so should not have the [tag:c#] tag) strongly suggests you failed to do any research on the question yourself.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a "port my code for me" site; it's a place where people who have made an honest effort to solve their own problem and still are having trouble can get help. If you feel you fall into that category, then fix your question by providing a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried, with a clear explanation of what specifically you're having trouble with. Don't just ask people to write your code for you.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "optimum"? That's the same as saying "best"--it really doesn't tell us much.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for your passionate reply and you make a valid point. However, just downvoting a post without mentioning the slightest clue  as to why does not help me nor this community any further. It only leads to more questions. You are correct in that I should have provided my Ruby code. I will update my question. I am glad my comment got this conversation started :-).

Comment: @31eee384 I think we got a bit lost in translation. By using "optium" I was trying to refer to the best practice of most commonly used method as there a most probably multiple ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: To sum up: I understand that so is not a "port my code" website. I just thought giving a clear c# example of what I was trying to accomplish would make it easier to communicate my issue.

Comment: _"downvoting a post without mentioning the slightest clue as to why does not help me nor this community any further"_ -- I agree that failing to comment to explain a downvote helps you _less_ than is otherwise possible. But the downvote itself is still a signal to you (i.e. results in you having more information than you had before), and so should at least help a _little_. And the comment is primarily for you; the downvote itself is what helps the community, and so is in fact quite helpful to the community as a whole.

Comment: In any case, you don't get to decide under what conditions someone downvotes. It may be frustrating to you to see a downvote without a comment, but your best defense there is to learn how to better present your questions, not to complain about the lack of a comment.

Comment: _"But the downvote itself is still a signal to you (i.e. results in you having more information than you had before), and so should at least help a little"_ -- If by "more information" you mean having no clue what I did wrong, then you are correct :-). _"your best defense there is to learn how to better present your questions, not to complain about the lack of a comment"_ -- The lack of a comment puts a cap on the learning potential of the down vote. Agreed on all your other comments though, which are more educational then the down vote -- thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is literally similar, but if you're using it for, say, binary file writing, not that useful:

```
'deadbeef'.scan(/../).map(&:hex)
[222, 173, 190, 239]
```

This is similar in spirit, since in Ruby strings in `Encoding:ASCII-8BIT` are what you'd normally use for a byte array:

```
'deadbeef'.scan(/../).map(&:hex).pack('C*')
"\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF"
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a go later today.

Comment: This works. Thank you very much! Learned some new Ruby stuff today :-).